# jQuery.ajax, PHP, HTTP Hyperlink download not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download, counter

I want to implement a simple counter to keep track of how many times a file was downloaded. We are talking big files here, so there's no way I will use readfile(), fpassthru() or similar which will load the whole file into php's memory.

Also, for this solution I want to use direct links and then update the counter via jQuery.ajax. I chose this way because a download.php with X-Sendfile didn't work out for me - often times I received multiple calls to the script for a single download, which messed up my counting completely. (This might be due to Chrome's extra-request for the favicon, but I'm not sure. Also, this is not the question.)

This is basically my index.html:

```
<a href="downloads/bla.zip"><span class="countDownload">bla</span></a>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").on("click", ".countDownload", function() {
        var filename = $(this).parent().attr("href");
        filename = filename.split("/");
        filename = filename[filename.length - 1]

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "counter.php?file=" + filename
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            alert("yes");
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("no");
        });

        // if this is here, ajax works, but download fails
        return false;


    });
});
```

If the "return false;" is there, the ajax request will succeed, but the file download will be suppressed.
If the "return false;" is not there, the ajax request will fail ("canceled"), but in turn the file download is working fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's basically no reason why the class to trigger the ajax is in the <span>; I think it could be in the <a> as well.

Comment: try putting it in the `<a>` and see what happens

Comment: Doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% untested, but just an idea...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").on("click", ".countDownload", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var filename = $(this).parent().attr("href");
    filename = filename.split("/");
    filename = filename[filename.length - 1]

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "counter.php?file=" + filename
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        alert("yes");
        window.location.href = "*****URL******"+filename;
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("no");
    });

    // if this is here, ajax works, but download fails
    return false;


});
});
```

Obviously fill in your own URL.

Comment: The combination of e.preventDefault() and later the window.location.href is actually working. The 'return false;' is not even necessary anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
<a href="downloads/bla.zip" id="download" style="display:none"></a>
<span class="countDownload">bla</span>


$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").on("click", ".countDownload", function() {
    var filename = $("#download").attr("href");
    filename = filename.split("/");
    filename = filename[filename.length - 1]

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "counter.php?file=" + filename
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        alert("yes");
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("no");
    });

    $("#download").trigger("click");
    return false;


});
});
```

first it will through your `ajax` request then triggers the click event of `anchor`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<div class="result"></div>
<button url="downloads/bla.zip">Click to download the file</button>
```

Your Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('button').on('click',function()
    {
        var filename = $(this).attr('url');
        var request = $.ajax(
        {
            url: "download_file.php?file=" + filename
        });
        request.done(function(msg)
        {
            $('.result').html('Thank you for downloading!');
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
            $('.result').html('Download failed!');
        });
    });
});
```

download_file.php?file=downloads/bla.zip:

```
    //First find this file :)
if(!empty($_POST['file']))
{
    $dirpath = 'location/of/file/'; 
    if(file_exists($dirpath))
    {
        $file = $dirpath.$_POST['file'];
        header('Content-Description: Secure file download');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        //DO YOUR COUNTING SOMEWHERE HERE:
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    //LOG ERROR HERE:
    exit;
}
```

To secure your files a little bit put this .htaccess in your download folder:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

I did not test the above. Hope you can figure it out yourself from here. Good luck

Comment: My explanation of the problem explicitly said not to use readfile(), fpassthru() or similar.

Comment: When you use exit; function it shouldn't count twice. I use a similar code.

Comment: How's that? It gets called twice, so what difference does it make if you use exit? It will get called anyway.

Comment: There are multiple ways to prevent the multiple requests. Logging a session on request, or log it into your database etc. You could easily set a time stamp and then ofcourse check the last request time for each file. How large are those files if I may ask?